# Google drive google document acces issue

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

```
# flutter developer
Google drive api
GET /drive/v3/files/{fileId}/export
```

error:

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob').

doesn't working flutter web

code

```
Future<void> exportFile() async {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{myfileid}/export';

    final HttpRequest xhr = HttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
        'Authorization', 'Bearer ${googleSignInAuthentication!.accessToken}');
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onLoad.listen((event) {
      print("---- ${xhr.status}");
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        var blob = xhr.response;
        var url = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
        var anchor = AnchorElement();
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.download = 'exported_file.pdf'; // Specify the desired filename
        anchor.click();
        Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
      } else {
        print('Error exporting file: ${xhr.status}');
        print('Error exporting file: ${xhr.responseText}');
      }
    });
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Please show your code